# Does Ejabberd only support chat functionality or can i extend it to support my whole website hosted on apache server

Tags: web, xmpp, integration, ejabberd

I am planning to build a social networking website like facebook supporting chat functionality . I want to implement chat functionality through Ejabberd server . Rest of the features are implemented in apache server .

I am not sure whether i need to extend Ejabberd server and port website from apache server to Ejabberd server or find a way to connect apache server to ejabberd server in case of chat request .

If i connect apache server to ejabberd server then should i go with default mnesia database or mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for Apache to know about ejabberd's database — why should it?

Instead, you code your website as usually and then hook ejabberd up to it to provide the chat functionality using [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) (for instance, via [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/) or something other.  "Full-blown" web chat clients exist as well — [there are hordes of them](https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) (plus just search the web).

There *will* be the problem of user authentication/registration but you can either have transient users (if you unly need public chats (rooms) or make ejabberd use the same MySQL database the website engine uses — [ejabberd can do that](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#odbc). Another solution is to enable [external authentication](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#extauth) in ejabberd — where it uses a program (written by you) to authenticate its users; such a program is then free to query the same database the website engine uses which solves the problem of imposing a specific schema in the data base.  Another bonus is that it's easier to change the database backend when needed.